# Lightning Quick Action to be available on certain conditions?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-quickaction

I currently disable the UI and call the apex controller on `doInit` of the controller.js and if the UI is valid to be used at the time, enable them, otherwise close the quick action window.

Is there any other way (a cleaner way) to run the check before component window is presented? or even before the button is rendered?

Comment: Have you thought about using record types and page layouts so that you can add/remove the action in question so that users don’t even see it when certain criteria is not met?

Comment: if you have any documentations on those, it would be great